# has anyone used the Cork library for authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, wsgi, bottle

I'm looking for a good authentication/authorization framework for [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).  I would love something that is fast and easy to use.

I've seen recommendations for [repoze.what](http://what.repoze.org/docs/1.0/) and [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/), but their documentation looks scary (I'm not sure what to even make of the repoze.who documentation).

There seems to be a new framework in play called [Cork](http://cork.firelet.net/).  It looks super easy to use.  Has anyone here actually used it in a project?  Also, what do you guys think of the saving of user credentials in a file (as opposed to a db table)?

Comment: Cork started just a few months ago. I already tried it, looks awesome, but never deployed it in production, because I still use repoze.who/what is my projects. I plan to change that ASAP.

Comment: @iurisilvio Cool - I've just started with it too, I agree it looks pretty awesome.  Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: repoze.what and repoze.who are hard to get started with, but given their feature-set I'd say they are worth it.